# Accidently enabled Airplane Mode. Can't turn it off

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, airplane-mode

About a week ago I accidentally enabled Airplane Mode on my Lenovo T430s with Ubuntu 20.04.2, and it said:

> "Use hardware switch to turn off"

There's a hardware switch on the right side of the laptop similar to this, and I tried toggling it, but nothing happened.

[image: similar to this]

I also tried pressing Fn + F5, but literally all that happened was this toast message popping up.

[image: this]

I also tried rfkill with no luck, and today I even went as far as re-installing Ubuntu thinking that would solve the issue, but nope, still locked in Airplane Mode...

Comment: How did you enable it?

Comment: No idea. I think I accidentally hit some button.

Comment: If there is an Ubuntu keyboard shortcut, review keyboard shortcuts in your system settings. If it's a hardware keyboard shortcut, review the documentation for your device

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1421213/edit) your question and add the output of `rfkill list`. Be sure to use code formatting (use the "{}" icon), so your output is easy for us to read.

Comment: Also, tell us which version of Ubuntu you are using, and which kernel version (i.e. the output of `uname -r`).

Comment: If the hardware switch will not turn off the Wifi, you really might want to contact Lenovo support to see if you can get the hardware switch to work.  They might know of a hidden setting somewhere to remedy your issue.

Comment: At boot, press the hotkey to enter the UEFI/BIOS menu system and look for a setting, where airplane mode can be turned on or off. Maybe, in one of the [sub]menus, there is a line for it.

Comment: Or, is it possible that an upgrade brought a hardware driver, that is not compatible with your wifi hardware? Or maybe the wifi hardware broke down physically? These alternatives are not likely, probably you can find where to change a setting to make wifi work again. - One alternative is to try an older or newer version of Ubuntu Desktop: [18.04.1 LTS](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/bionic/) or [22.04 LTS](https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/) to get other kernels and hardware drivers.